# Disable FastInfoset (force XML) on Apache CXF when using the client

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, fastinfoset

I need to force Apache CXF to send XML requests and handle only XML responses when I'm client and I have no control over the server or the configuration (I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200863/how-to-disable-fastinfoset-in-jax-ws-and-always-return-xml-results) but it only apply to the server). Right now it's always using FastInfoset which is great for performances but is causing some issue and I would like to be able to disable it but I didn't find much information on FastInfoset on the Internet and how should go about disabling it. Do you have any clues?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to force XML setting the `Accept` header to `application/xml`. The server should provide a non-encoded response

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if the remote server supports pure XML responses. Most of the servers which do support both Fastinfoset and pure XML are looking into `Accept` header from the request to decide in which format to return the response.
So you can try to force the XML response by sending the `Accept: application/xml` header with each of your requests.
For that you will need to create a CXF out interceptor and register it with your application.

Following Interceptor will always set `Accept: application/xml`

```
public class HttpHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>{
    public XmlOnlyInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.POST_PROTOCOL);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        Map<String, List> headers = (Map<String, List>)message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
        headers.put("Accept", Collections.singletonList("application/xml"));
    }
}
```

To register it use follwoing configuration

```
<jaxws:client id="clientBean" serviceClass="org.example.service.ServicePortType"
          address="example.org/src/service/ServicePort">
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.example.interceptor.HttpHeaderInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
```

Comment: I didn't had the time to test this, I'll validate when I would be able to, but you deserve the bounty. Thanks.